# Substituting Soy milk +vegan butter for whole milk +margerine for whipped fluffy icing

Tags: vegan, icing, soymilk

I would like to make an icing for my family member who has a milk allergy.
I have a recipe for whipped fluffy icing using whole milk, flour, sugar and margerine. It is cooked, then cooled and additional steps follow. Will it turn
out well if I substitute soy milk and vegan margerine? Also, can it be refrigerated?

Comment: It would be helpful if you were to add the actual recipe to the question.

Comment: "vegan butter" is a synonym for "high quality margarine"....

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Soy milk (or any other non-dairy milk such as almond milk) can be used as a direct substitute for dairy milk. (Your mileage may vary if you make homemade soy milk, which may have a more "beany" flavor.) In addition, vegan margarine such as Earth Balance can be used as a direct substitute for butter. In fact, these are two of the easiest vegan substitutions.